# Program throws unexpected error while parsing date?

Tags: java, scala, datetime

```
def toSec(time: String): Long = {

   DateTimeFormat.forPattern( """yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"""").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Hong_Kong")).parseDateTime(time).getMillis
```

}

```
16/01/05 14:16:26 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 6) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2015/06/23 07:57:30" is too short
at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:899)
at DataCreation.ProcessData$.toSec(package.scala:214)
at DataCreation.ProcessData$$anonfun$12.apply(package.scala:106)
at DataCreation.ProcessData$$anonfun$12.apply(package.scala:106)
```

When Ever I try and execute the function it would raise following exception, although it appears fine to me?  Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are these duplicated " about? Can you edit them away or are they like this in your code?

Answer (score 1):

You should Drop """ replace by "

```
scala> DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Hong_Kong")).parseDateTime("2015/06/23 07:57:30").getMillis

    res1: Long = 1435017450000
```

Comment: Yep, I identified the small problem :P